# Does Promise.all() execute an array of functions or do they execute when you put them into the array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Since `await` does not work inside `Array.map` or `Array.reduce`, can you do something like the following or would this be considered misuse of `Promise.all`? Normally, `neo4j.session()` would be awaited.

```
// inside a function

const QUERY = 'MATCH (n) RETURN n'
const argsArray = [{ sample: 'sadf' }, { sample: 'sadf' }, { sample: 'sadf' }]

const runQueries = argsArray.map(obj => neo4j.session.run(QUERY, obj.sample))

await Promise.all(runQueries)
      .then(results => results.forEach(result => console.log(result)))
```

Comment: `Promise.all(runQueries).then(console.log)` is cleaner

Comment: @dandavis I seriously doubt he actually plans to console.log anything, that's just a stand in for additional business logic.

Comment: That is a correct assessment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Promise.all() execute an array of functions?

No its an array of promises

> or do they execute when you put them into the array?

Exactly, When you build the Promises they're  executed.

> would this be considered misuse of Promise.all?

No this is totally fine, its actually the point of Promise.all.

However you might do (one after another instead of parallel execution) :

```
(async function(){

for(const obj of argsArray)
  console.log( await neo4j.session.run(QUERY, obj.sample));

})()
```

Comment: what does "_build the Promises_" mean? is that a babel thing?

Comment: @dandavis i mean `new Promise()` with that. If its misleading feel free to edit

Comment: hmm. he's not using `new Promise()`, so it's still unclear (more hidden) to noobs. not sure how to clarify...

Comment: @dandavis i think its fine as it is, if someone is unshure he will probably find our conversation ;)

Answer (score 3):

`async.await` is supposed to be syntactic sugar for sequential promise chains. Considering that database queries are supposed to run concurrently, it's perfectly fine to use `await Promise.all(...)` in such cases.

`Promise.all` accepts an array of promises (more specifically, an iterable), and promises start to execute at the moment when they are created. It may be the moment prior to `Promise.all` call:

```
const promises = [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)];
// promises have been created at this point
Promise.all(promises).then(...)
```

Or it may be not. If an iterable is not an array but a generator, promises will be lazily created during `Promise.all` call:

```
const promiseGen = (function* () {
  yield Promise.resolve(1);
  yield Promise.resolve(2);
})();
// promises have not been created yet at this point
Promise.all(promiseGen).then(...)
// promises have been created
```